# Convert symbols to readable

Tags: php, decode

`echo $title` gives me something like `\u00ca\u00e0\u00f7\u00e5\u00eb\u00e8`.

It should be a readable text instead. How do I decode it correctly?

I've tried `html_entity_decode($title, 0, 'UTF-8')`, but it doesn't work for non-english languages. I get something like `Êà÷åëè` instead of a real text.

Comment: `Êà÷åëè` is what I get too with `json_decode('"\u00ca\u00e0\u00f7\u00e5\u00eb\u00e8"')` You're using maybe the wrong encoding.

Comment: maybe, I'm not sure about the encoding of `$title`.

Comment: what's the original text? So that we can have some clue?

Comment: any help? what's wrong with this string?

Comment: The string is absolutely valid. And the output too...

Answer (score 0):

Try `echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8");`

Comment: doesn't help. seems something bad with encoding of `$title`. Encoding of the php file is utf-8

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$title = mb_convert_encoding($title,'HTML-ENTITIES','utf-8');
```

hope this will work for you.
Edit:
Try this if it works

```
$title = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $title);
```